# What do superclass implementation of activity lifecycle in android do?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, superclass, super

I have been learning android programming and i noticed that all activity life cycle methods have a super class that is implemented in the beginning.

The Android documentation also says, "Your implementation of these lifecycle methods must always call the superclass implementation before doing any work" regarding the life cycle methods.

What i am curious about is why is this necessary and what exactly do these super class do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take a look at [`Activity`'s source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java).

For example, the [`onCreate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29) method (line 879):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (DEBUG_LIFECYCLE) Slog.v(TAG, "onCreate " + this + ": " + savedInstanceState);
    if (mLastNonConfigurationInstances != null) {
        mAllLoaderManagers = mLastNonConfigurationInstances.loaders;
    }
    if (mActivityInfo.parentActivityName != null) {
        if (mActionBar == null) {
            mEnableDefaultActionBarUp = true;
        } else {
            mActionBar.setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        Parcelable p = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(FRAGMENTS_TAG);
        mFragments.restoreAllState(p, mLastNonConfigurationInstances != null
                ? mLastNonConfigurationInstances.fragments : null);
    }
    mFragments.dispatchCreate();
    getApplication().dispatchActivityCreated(this, savedInstanceState);
    mCalled = true;
}
```

---

When you extend `Activity` with somthing like:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Some stuff
}
```

You actually call the above method by calling `super.onCreate()`.

Why is it required? It's a requirement of the Android platform, as the `onCreate()` method performs essential operations for the activity's lifecycle.

Comment: What have you understood from the above code? OP want description not source code

Comment: sorry but the source code above is written nicely enough that you can see pretty well whats going on - or you don't think so? basically it checks if there should be a home button in the action bare, are any fragments to restore and some other initial stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If your class extends any other class and You have methods that implements methods from that extended class.
But You don't want do all implementation by yourself. You call super.your_Method_That_Has_Implementation_In_Extented_Class();

It says: in this moment do what is in implementation of myMethod in class from which I extend my class.

You can also see this tutorial about that:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html